# Why visual studio crashes on changing the "ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Ssss1 }" when i try to change "sss1" to "Programs"

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, mvvm, binding

I am trying to develop a silverlight application which crashes when i change the "ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Ssss1 }" when i try to change "sss1" to "Programs" (I mean when i try to do

ItemsSource="{Binding
 Path=Programs }"

Then
 it crashes the Visual Studio.

In Explain (what i am trying to do is) :

I am beginnerof silverlight application using c# and xaml. What i am trying to do is to display information like:

```
SerialNumber  FirstName LastName //These are headingand below is the data
s0             ss1       ss1L
s1             ss2       ss2L
```

where `s0 ss1 ss1L` and `s1 ss2 ss2`L must be List.

What My problem is :

It just show the headings but not data below like this: http://prntscr.com/3axadr But show nothing below the headings.

My code is below :

My Project Name is DEV_CENTER and MainPage.Xaml is

```
<UserControl x:Class="DEV_CENTER.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
              xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DEV_CENTER"
             xmlns:data="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:ProgramViewModel x:Key="ProgramViewModel"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <data:DataGrid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="gridPrograms" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Programs }" IsReadOnly="True"  DataContext="{StaticResource ProgramViewModel}" >
            <data:DataGrid.Columns>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="SerialNumber" Binding="{Binding Path=SerialNumber}" Width="2*"></data:DataGridTextColumn>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}" Width="2*"></data:DataGridTextColumn>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="LastName" Binding="{Binding Path=LastName}" Width="3*"></data:DataGridTextColumn>
            </data:DataGrid.Columns> 
        </data:DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My ProgramViewModel.cs (ViewModel) file is :

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel; 
namespace DEV_CENTER
{
    public class ProgramViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        #region PROPERTIES
        public ObservableCollection<Program> Programs 
        {
            get
            { 
                return Programs;
            }
            set 
            { 
                OnPropertyChanged("Programs"); 
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public ProgramViewModel()
        {
            Programs = new ObservableCollection<Program>(getAllPrograms());
            MessageBox.Show("check1");  
        }
        #endregion 
        public List<Program> getAllPrograms()
        {
            List<Program> programs = new List<Program>();
            Program p1 = new Program();
            p1.SerialNumber = "ss0";
            p1.FirstName = "ss1";
            p1.LastName = "ss1L";
            Program p2 = new Program();
            p2.SerialNumber = "Program 2";
            p2.FirstName = "ss1";
            p2.LastName = "ss2L";
            programs.Add(p1);
            programs.Add(p2);
            return programs;
        }


        #region EVENTS
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion 

    }
}
```

And Program.cs (Model) is :

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace DEV_CENTER 
{
    public class Program
    {
        #region PROPERTIES
        public string SerialNumber 
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string FirstName 
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string LastName 
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        #endregion

        public Program()
        {
            SerialNumber = "";
            FirstName = "";
            LastName = "";

        }
    }
}
```

It's my almost full project. You can use all code to test.
 Is there anything wrong in Mvvm logic ? or anything else ? Why it crashes ?

Comment: are you saying that visual studio itself crashes?  or your program crashes?  if your program crashes, use the debugger, it should stop exactly where the problem is.

Comment: @JohnGardner When i edit ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Ssss1 }" to ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Programs }" it gives http://prntscr.com/3aymzo .

Comment: (i'm presuming VS is crashing since it is trying to show the xaml designer, and the stack overflow happens inside the xaml designer, bringing down VS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a stack overflow:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Program> Programs 
    {
        get
        { 
            return Programs; // upper case p!  recursively calling itself!
        }
    ...
    }
```

that property is calling itself recursively forever.

you need to add a field, like

```
 private ObservableCollection<Program> programs; // note lower case p!

    public ObservableCollection<Program> Programs // upper case p!
    {
        get
        { 
            return this.programs; // lower case p!
        }
    ...
    }
```

also, your setter is never doing anything, so that's not good:

```
        set 
        { 
            OnPropertyChanged("Programs"); 
        }
```

that is just firing a property change, it isn't ever setting a value!

the complete property should look like:

```
    private ObservableCollection<Program> programs; // note lower case p!

    public ObservableCollection<Program> Programs // upper case p!
    {
        get
        { 
            return this.programs; // lower case p!
        }

        set
        {
            this.programs = value; // lower case p
            OnPropertyChanged("Programs");
        }        
    }
```

Comment: in general, on most versions of .net, if your program crashes with no info, it is probably a stack overflow caused like this.

Comment: I done this : private ObservableCollection<Program> programs; // note lower case p!

    public ObservableCollection<Program> Programs // upper case p!
    {
        get
        { 
            return this.programs; // lower case p!
        } set { OnPropertyChanged("Program"); }} but as i again change "ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Programs }" IT AGAIN CRASHES. And when i restart VS2012 it don't show even the changes i done in get set.

Comment: i can tell you, from your code as pasted above, you have a stack overflow in the programs property.

Comment: But how to solve it i tried to make the changes in get set and the programs(lower case) declaration, and when i again make change in Xaml, It again do the same problem. HOW TO SOLVE IT ? Please help me..I am lost..

Comment: Thanks.... But even after this edit, when i make changes in Xaml it again do the same. And when VS2012 restarts those changes are lost.I again find the same data as before (I mean the same Upper case Programs).

Comment: make sure you close the xaml file, so the xaml designer it is no longer open, if it is the cause of the issues.  change your files save.  close the file.  reopen it. does it include your changes? it should, you just saved it. build.  if the build succeeded, the files are not the same as before.

Comment: Yes the changes are saved in get set. But as i write "Programs" in Xaml it immediately crashes. whereas when i write "Prog" or "Progra" or anything it don't carsh but it has just problem with "Programs".

Comment: The error is : Unexpected token Close in Rule: NamedArg ::= PROPERTYNAME '=' @(STRING | MarkupExtension), in '{Binding Path= }'. C:\Users\shekhar_shekhawat\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DEV_CENTER\DEV_CENTER\MainPage.Xaml

Comment: another thing even i have commented the full ProgramViewModel class it still crashes :P

Comment: delete all your obj/bin directories. and try again to make sure there's no bad stuff around.  if it only crashes with programs, try naming the thing something else

Comment: where are these Obj/bin directories located in VStudio ?

Comment: And it crashes with "Programs" not "programs" . What should i put there Lower case or Uppercase ?

Comment: I have tears of Joy in my eyes brother :) changing names worked :)